# How to convert RDD[List[Int]] to DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I hava a `RDD[List[Int]]` ,I don not know the count of `list[Int]`,I want to convert i `Rdd[List[Int]]` to `DataFrame`,How should I do?

this is my input:

```
    val l1=Array(1,2,3,4)
    val l2=Array(1,2,3,4)
    val Lz=Seq(l1,l2)
    val rdd1=sc.parallelize(Lz,2)
```

this is my expect result:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3| _4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: You don't know the count of `l1` and `l2` but will they always be of the same length?

Comment: The count of l1 and l2 is same,but the count of list[Int] is not alwary be of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

```
val l1=Array(1,2,3,4)
val l2=Array(1,2,3,4)
val Lz=Seq(l1,l2)
val df = sc.parallelize(Lz,2).map{
    case Array(val1, val2, val3, val4) => (val1, val2, val3, val4)
}.toDF

df.show
// +---+---+---+---+
// | _1| _2| _3| _4|
// +---+---+---+---+
// |  1|  2|  3|  4|
// |  1|  2|  3|  4|
// +---+---+---+---+
```

If you have lots of columns, you would need to proceed differently but you need to know the schema of your data otherwise you'll not be able to perform the following :

```
val sch = df.schema // I just took the schema from the old df but you can add one programmatically 

val df2 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Lz,2).map{ Row.fromSeq(_) }, sch)

df2.show
// +---+---+---+---+
// | _1| _2| _3| _4|
// +---+---+---+---+
// |  1|  2|  3|  4|
// |  1|  2|  3|  4|
// +---+---+---+---+
```

Unless you provide a schema, you won't be able to do much except having an array column :

```
val df3 = sc.parallelize(Lz,2).toDF
// df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: array<int>]
df3.show
// +------------+
// |       value|
// +------------+
// |[1, 2, 3, 4]|
// |[1, 2, 3, 4]|
// +------------+
df3.printSchema
//root
// |-- value: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

Comment: I don not the count of list[Int] ,so I can not get schema

Comment: The count of l1 and l2 is same,but the count of list[Int] is not alwary be of the same length.

Comment: You can't do that. Unless you provide a schema you'll just have an array of entries

Comment: I hava a Array[String], the count of Array and List is same,the value of Array is the the column name,can I do that?

Comment: @mentongwu I have given all the possible ways anything else would be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some other and better functional way to do this, but this works too:

```
def getSchema(myArray : Array[Int]): StructType = {
    var schemaArray = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[StructField]()
    for((el,idx) <- myArray.view.zipWithIndex){
        schemaArray += StructField("col"+idx , IntegerType, true)
    }
    StructType(schemaArray)
}

val l1=Array(1,2,3,4)
val l2=Array(1,2,3,4)
val Lz=Seq(l1,l2)
val rdd1=sc.parallelize(Lz,2).map(Row.fromSeq(_))
val schema = getSchema(l1) //Since both arrays will be of same type and size
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd1, schema)
df.show()

+----+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|   4|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|
+----+----+----+----+
```